# Weblogic cluster session replication type doesn't work

Tags: weblogic, weblogic12c

I have a cluster and I want to use a single session for this cluster. I mean all servers in this cluster will share same session. From Cluster config page(I use adminconsole) I choose cross-cluster replication type as WAN(I also tried MAN) but My servers still doesn't share the same session. I got 2 servers and 2 sessions one for each. Do I need to do something more?

**EDIT:** I have only one web application call it sample.war running on a cluster.

Answer (score 0):

Your application needs the following configuration:

```
   <session-descriptor>
        <persistent-store-type>replicated_if_clustered</persistent-store-type>
        <sharing-enabled>true</sharing-enabled>  
    </session-descriptor>
```

Also make sure you are using a load balancer or the weblogic provided HttpClusterServlet.

Comment: session decriptor doesn't work. I have a simple application and there is no database. Do I need to use a load balancer or HttpClusterServlet?

Comment: I believe you do, the session is probably stored as a cookie on the users browser, so your side needs to appear to be the same host whether the requests are filled by one or the other instance. HTH

Answer (score 0):

Logon to admin console,

Goto clusters -> select the cluster -> goto Configuration Tab -> Goto Replication Tab -> Tick the option Secure Replication Enabled

Restart managed nodes once if required.

Those two servers in the cluster will use the same session

Comment: there is no advanced tab and there is no options like "Enable Session replication".

Comment: Still servers doesn't share same session